# Roman Number to Integer

Tags: programming-challenge, typescript, roman-numerals

## Problem Definition

> Roman numerals are represented by seven different symbols: `I`, `V`, `X`, `L`, `C`, `D` and `M`.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc|}
    Symbol & Value \\
\hline 
    I & 1 \\
    V & 5 \\
    X & 10 \\
    L & 50 \\
    C & 100 \\
    D & 500 \\
    M & 1000 \\
\end{array}$$

> For example, two is written as `II` in Roman numeral, just two one's added together. Twelve is written as, `XII`, which is simply `X` + `II`. The number twenty seven is written as `XXVII`, which is `XX` + `V` + `II`.
>
> Roman numerals are usually written largest to smallest from left to right. However, the numeral for four is not `IIII`. Instead, the number four is written as `IV`. Because the one is before the five we subtract it making four. The same principle applies to the number nine, which is written as `IX`. There are six instances where subtraction is used:
>
> `I` can be placed before `V` (`5`) and `X` (`10`) to make `4` and `9`.
>   `X` can be placed before `L` (`50`) and `C` (`100`) to make `40` and `90`.
>   `C` can be placed before `D` (`500`) and `M` (`1000`) to make `400` and `900`.
>   Given a roman numeral, convert it to an integer. Input is guaranteed to be within the range from `1` to `3999`.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> **Input**: `"III"`
>   **Output**: `3`
>
> **Input**: `"IV"`
>   **Output**: `4`
>
> **Input**: `"IX"`
>   **Output**: `9`
>
> **Input**: `"LVIII"`
>   **Output**: `58` (`L` = `50`, `V` = `5`, `III` = `3`).
>
> **Input**: `"MCMXCIV"`
>   **Output**: `1994` (`M` = `1000`, `CM` = `900`, `XC` = `90` and `IV` = `4`).

### Solution

**Approach:** In my solution I decided to use a simple state machine which seems elegant to me. But do you agree? Could I do better?

**Criteria:** Readability over performance. I care the most about the code to be easy to understand. Performance is important, but only in terms of "big-O" notation.

**Note:** `.` "next symbol" represents "any other case" or "otherwise" branch.

```
type Action = { value: number, skipNextSymbol: boolean };
type Transitions = { [nextSymbol: string]: Action };
type StateMachine = { [currentSymbol: string]: Transitions };

export const stateMachine: StateMachine = {
  'I': {
    'V': { value: 4, skipNextSymbol: true },
    'X': { value: 9, skipNextSymbol: true },
    '.': { value: 1, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'V': {
    '.': { value: 5, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'X': {
    'L': { value: 40, skipNextSymbol: true },
    'C': { value: 90, skipNextSymbol: true },
    '.': { value: 10, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'L': {
    '.': { value: 50, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'C': {
    'D': { value: 400, skipNextSymbol: true },
    'M': { value: 900, skipNextSymbol: true },
    '.': { value: 100, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'D': {
    '.': { value: 500, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
  'M': {
    '.': { value: 1000, skipNextSymbol: false },
  },
};

export const romanToInt = function(roman: string): number {
  if (!roman || !roman.length) throw new Error(`${roman} is not a Roman number.`);

  const symbolQueue = roman.toUpperCase().split('');
  let resultNumber = 0;
  while (symbolQueue.length) {
    const currentSymbol = symbolQueue.shift()!;
    const transitions = stateMachine[currentSymbol];
    const nextSymbol = symbolQueue[0];
    const applicableTransition = transitions[nextSymbol] || transitions['.'];
    resultNumber += applicableTransition.value;
    if (applicableTransition.skipNextSymbol && symbolQueue.length)
      symbolQueue.shift();
  }
  return resultNumber;
};
```

### Tests

````
import { romanToInt } from '../src/leet-code/1-easy/13-roman-to-integer';

describe(romanToInt.name, () => {
  it('Should work', () => {
    interface TestCase {
      input: string;
      expectedOutput: number;
    };

    const testCases: TestCase[] = [
      { input: 'I', expectedOutput: 1 },
      { input: 'II', expectedOutput: 2 },
      { input: 'III', expectedOutput: 3 },
      { input: 'IV', expectedOutput: 4 },
      { input: 'V', expectedOutput: 5 },
      { input: 'VI', expectedOutput: 6 },
      { input: 'VII', expectedOutput: 7 },
      { input: 'VIII', expectedOutput: 8 },
      { input: 'IX', expectedOutput: 9 },
      { input: 'X', expectedOutput: 10 },
      { input: 'XI', expectedOutput: 11 },
      { input: 'XII', expectedOutput: 12 },
      { input: 'XIII', expectedOutput: 13 },
      { input: 'XIV', expectedOutput: 14 },
      { input: 'XV', expectedOutput: 15 },
      { input: 'XVI', expectedOutput: 16 },
      { input: 'XVII', expectedOutput: 17 },
      { input: 'XVIII', expectedOutput: 18 },
      { input: 'XIX', expectedOutput: 19 },
      { input: 'XX', expectedOutput: 20 },
      { input: 'XXX', expectedOutput: 30 },
      { input: 'XL', expectedOutput: 40 },
      { input: 'L', expectedOutput: 50 },
      { input: 'LX', expectedOutput: 60 },
      { input: 'LXX', expectedOutput: 70 },
      { input: 'LXXX', expectedOutput: 80 },
      { input: 'XC', expectedOutput: 90 },
      { input: 'C', expectedOutput: 100 },
      { input: 'CC', expectedOutput: 200 },
      { input: 'CCC', expectedOutput: 300 },
      { input: 'CD', expectedOutput: 400 },
      { input: 'D', expectedOutput: 500 },
      { input: 'DC', expectedOutput: 600 },
      { input: 'DCC', expectedOutput: 700 },
      { input: 'DCCC', expectedOutput: 800 },
      { input: 'CM', expectedOutput: 900 },
      { input: 'M', expectedOutput: 1000 },
      { input: 'MM', expectedOutput: 2000 },
      { input: 'MMM', expectedOutput: 3000 },
      { input: 'MMMM', expectedOutput: 4000 },
      { input: 'MMMMM', expectedOutput: 5000 },
      { input: 'MCMXCIX', expectedOutput: 1999 },
    ];
    testCases.forEach(testCase => {
      const { input, expectedOutput } = testCase;
      expect(romanToInt(input)).toEqual(expectedOutput);
    });
  });
});
```
````

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define each individual transition state since there's a simple general rule: total all the numerals, but subtract the ones that occur in front of a larger numeral.

```
function romanToInt(roman: string): number {
    const value: {[numeral: string]: number} = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    let prev = 0;
    let total = 0;
    for (const numeral of roman.split('').reverse()) {
        const current = value[numeral];  // this will throw on an invalid numeral
        if (current >= prev)
            total += current;
        else 
            total -= current;
        prev = current;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Good observation. I can see how your code will allow invalid inputs (i.e. `IVX`). My code suffers from the same issue. But at least your code is more compact... If I was to make my code work correctly against the invalid inputs (which is throw an error), I'd actually need to define _more_ transitions -- allowed only. Thanks for the review Sam. Upvoted

Comment: If you wanted to catch more invalid numbers, you could add more rules, like: when you subtract a lesser number from a greater number it has to be at least 5x smaller (i.e. no "VX").  Careful making it too strict, IIRC the Romans themselves would sometimes do slightly irregular things.  :)